# xrandr (display) problem

Tags: debian, xfce, xrandr, display

I am running Debian Jessie with xfce. For the past 3 days I have been trying to get my dual monitors to work right. They are functioning, but that isn't saying much. I have my second monitor to the left of my main monitor. I have to run a xrandr script at startup to get my main monitor to use 1920x1080 resolution. I have my second monitor rotated left and at 1600x1200 resolution. I do want this to be extended, not mirrored.

Basically, my second monitor has all my icons and originally had my taskbars. I need that stuff on my main monitor! The display is extended, but there is no separation between the 2 where my icons and everything will default to my main monitor. I was able to change my taskbars in XFCE to my main one, which is where I want everything, but my icons still go to the second monitor.

My conky config is also messing up as I have it placed to the bottom left and it is putting it to the bottom left of my second monitor, not my first (main). I have set it as primary and have extensively tried arandr and a lot of xrandr stuff. I have to use xrandr and a .sh script at startup to get my resolution applied to my main monitor. The second monitor's resolution isn't a problem, but it seems to be defaulting to having the main's content, with the desktop icons on it and everything. Sorry, I feel like this is confusing.

Here is my resolution.sh file I run at startup:
VGA1 is the one I want to be my main (all icons and taskbars on it) 
HDMI1 is the second monitor to the left of my main (it defaults to having all icons and conky configs on or halfway between it and my main monitor.

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1080
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080 --primary

xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1600x1200 --pos 0x0 --rotate left --output DP1 --off --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1600x0 --rotate normal
xrandr --output HDMI1 --left-of VGA1
```

I know not all of that code was required to get my settings where they are, but I have been trying everything to get this to work!

Comment: Have you tried writing an `xorg.conf` for your configuration? This means X starts in the correct configuration, and doesn't have to change it with `xrandr` afterwards. `man xorg.conf`, esp. the Serverlayout section. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=xorg.conf+dual+monitor) for tutorials. Look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to see what the X server actually did. In general, the idea is to have one big "virtual" screen for both monitors, and both monitors then display part of that screen.